# Sentence structure of "Two X do not a Y make"

Tags: sentence-structure, inversion

> Two cuts do not an EV price war make.

Source: [Electric vehicles defy price war after Ford and Tesla discounts](https://www.ft.com/content/ffb0f01d-e341-4402-817e-087074312862)

The likely meaning is "Two cuts do not make an EV price war." But I've never seen a sentence inversion like this. Is there any explanation or other examples?

Comment: From Lovelace's [To Althea from Prison](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44657/to-althea-from-prison): _Stone Walls do not a Prison make_

Comment: Or in my mind more likely, 'one swallow does not a summer make', attributed to Aristotle, c.350 BC.

Comment: "One swallow does not make a summer" is more common than the inverted version (or you can use [doesn't](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-swallow-doesn-t-make-a-summer)). Lovelace is more likely the origin.

Answer (score 1):

This particular phrase, "do not a...make," is [a specific English idiom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52596/proper-usage-origin-of-the-generic-phrase-action-phrase-does-not-a-noun-mak). So, while the word order certainly sounds unusual, it would be seen as invoking that idiom, rather than as a grammatical mistake.